# Finding a function from requirements

Tags: functions

I want to find an equation f(x) which satisfies the following requirements:

$$ f(0) = 0 $$
$$ f(4) = 1 $$
$$ \lim_{h\to 0}f'(h)=\infty $$
$$ f'(4)=-0.25 $$
f(x) has to be a continuous and smooth function with only one extremum, so no wiggly wiggly functions to just satisfy the needs.

Is there a smart way to do this? My assignment says the function will be $a*sqrt(x)-bx$, buut it also says i should plug in values to try and find the correct ones for the function to meet the set requirements, which i really do not like. If there is a way to find a possible function without knowing the form of the function, i would like to know that.

Comment: Knowing both $f(4)$ and $f'(4)$ lets you set up a system of equations to find $a,b$.

Comment: I updated the question, i can find find the values by solving two equations with two unknowns, however i would like to know if there is a way to find a function that meets my requirements without knowing the form of the function.

Comment: I believe that there are many functions satisfying your requirements, since those do not restrict how the function behaves around, say, 3 (except for continuous, smooth, monotone).

Comment: Yeah i expected that. Is there a way of getting to such a function? Just any one function that would meet the described requirements?

Comment: @iBoughtWinrar it's a bit tricky; because of the constraints $f (0)=0$ and $f'\rightarrow0$ at $x=0$. The latter suggests a term like $\frac {1}{x}$, but the former prohibits it as $f $ is defined at 0. Focusing in, you only need a negative exponent on $x $ after differentiation, so starting with a fractional exponent makes sense. A term like $\sqrt{x}$ seems like the simple realization of those two constraints. Then you're just tacking on the smallest polynomial that gets the rest of it to work. Hopefully this gives some insight into how you might do this with no guidance about the form.

Comment: This is what i was looking for. Thinking about it, the simplest function i could imagine, which would meet the requirements lim h->0 f'(h) = infinity and f'(4) = -0.25 is a squareroot function with a factor to make it end up decreasing at x = 4 and a term to subtract f(0) from the function so that f(0) becomes 0. But now that i already have the function form it does seem a lot easier than it first did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having to find a function with the said constraints gives me the first impression that this is a function with a fractional exponent such as a squareroot function. If we say its a squareroot function, we will need the function to be decreasing at x = 4, which means we need to subtract a second term depending on x, since this term should be 0 at x = 0. Thus we have $\sqrt x - bx$. To make this function meet the requirement $f(4)=1$, we would need $\sqrt x - 0.25x$.

$f'(4)$ for this function, however, would be 0, so we must need a factor for the $\sqrt x$, thus having the function $f(x)=a*\sqrt x - bx$. We can now solve for this function using two equations with two unknowns:

$$f(4)=1$$
$$f'(4)=-0.25$$

Answer (score 1):

Given the form of the function, you know:

$f(x) = a*x^{1/2} + bx$

Therefore:

$f(4) = a*4^{1/2} + b*4 = 1$

Then,

$f'(x) = 1/2*a*x^{-1/2} + b$

Therefore,

$f'(4) = 1/2*a*4^{-1/2} + b = -0.25$

Now you have two equations and two unknowns which you can solve for a and b.

Comment: I wanted to know if there was a way to find the function without knowing the form of the function at first. I think i can do the math to find the values for a and b myself. I will edit my qurestion to clarify this.